# Chrome Net Internals not same like before or in opera anymore

Tags: google-chrome

What Happens with my Chrome ? 
Inside chrome://net-internals/#events

> The net-internals events viewer and related functionality has been removed. Please use chrome://net-export to save netlogs and the external catapult netlog_viewer to view them.

I'm using Google Chrome Version 71.0.3578.80 (Official Build) (64-bit) two days ago it still work...

Actually Why they remove net-internals view ?

Comment: Well, did you try `chrome://net-export`?

Comment: already but it's harder to navigate i need to open the JSON in viewer first and keep load it, In Opera chrome://net-internals still same like before

Comment: Not in Opera 58.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, It's because my chrome forced update to 71 Version, it was 69 last time i use. Already trying to reinstall to 69 but still got forced update to 71.

[Chrome Update Log 70 - 71](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/70.0.3538.110..71.0.3578.80?pretty=fuller&n=10000)

I still can use chrome://net-export for troubleshooting my extension but this will slow down immensely my troubleshooting time.

Comment: is there a portable chrome app at version 69?

Answer (score 1):

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/6943864?hl=en

Seems Google doesn't want to answer the question.  Looking at the code it doesn't seem very large to me.  Not sure why they are using that as justification for removing it.

They talked about removing it in 2016 though.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Ll7T5cguj5m2DqkUTad5DWRCqtbQ3L1q9FRvTN5-Y28/edit#